# How to disable cash on delivery method for specific product in woocommerce

Tags: html, mysql, woocommerce

I post a product that not allowed to do cash on delivery payment I want online payment from that product so how I can specify online payment method to that specific product in woocommerce like providing a service online

I know how to disable and enable cash on delivery method but that will be disabled for all products and I don't want that

Please anyone can solve this problem how I can specify only one payment method that will be online payment method for that product

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways I know of this. First, using this awesome function by [Business Bloomer - Rodolfo Melogli](https://businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-disable-payment-method-for-specific-category/) by adding to your themes `functions.php`. Go to https://businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-disable-payment-method-for-specific-category/ and follow their instructions if you need help.

```
  /**
 * @snippet       Disable Payment Method for Specific Category
 * @how-to        Watch tutorial @ https://businessbloomer.com/?p=19055
 * @sourcecode    https://businessbloomer.com/?p=19892
 * @author        Rodolfo Melogli
 * @testedwith    WooCommerce 3.2.5
 */

add_filter( 'woocommerce_available_payment_gateways', 'bbloomer_unset_gateway_by_category' );

function bbloomer_unset_gateway_by_category( $available_gateways ) {
global $woocommerce;
$unset = false;
$category_ids = array( 8, 37 );
foreach ( $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents as $key => $values ) {
    $terms = get_the_terms( $values['product_id'], 'product_cat' );    
    foreach ( $terms as $term ) {        
        if ( in_array( $term->term_id, $category_ids ) ) {
            $unset = true;
            break;
        }
    }
}
    if ( $unset == true ) unset( $available_gateways['cheque'] );
    return $available_gateways;
}
```

The second method is by using a plugin, such as https://wordpress.org/plugins/conditional-payment-methods-for-woocommerce/. There are other plugins available, some free and some paid. Best to research them first as they often do a lot more than you'll want.

Comment: Thank you for your big reply I will follow your steps and tell you after sometime that will work or not

Comment: Follow the steps on https://businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-disable-payment-method-for-specific-category/. They deserve the ad revenue for writing it. I just passed on my previous research. Good luck.

Comment: Plus they are a great resource to customising Woocommerce.